# How to show min and max values while typing in text box dynamically using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to show min and max values of the text box while user typing the value in text box, if the user tab/move the cursor from textbox the message should be hide.

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-maxlength="20"  
       maxlength="20"  
       ng-minlength="10"  
       ng-model="value.x">
<p ng-show="value.x">
  Please enter above {{minlength}} and below {{maxlength}} characters 
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ng-focus and ng-blur directives to set visibility of your message.

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="show = true" ng-blur = "show=false"  ng-maxlength="20" maxlength = "20"  ng-minlength="10" ng-model="value.x"  >
<p ng-show="show == true">
  Please enter above {{minlength}} and below {{maxlength}} characters 
</p>
```